# Getting InvalidOperationException Error Stack Trace Only Has One Line

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010, error-handling

I am doing an asynchronous call to a server and trying to pass an object that holds two strings as a parameter. Somewhere along the way the object is serialized and sent in JSON format. The serialization is done via Newtonsoft.Json. I keep getting an error saying Incoming messages must have a body format of Raw. This is a custom error message.

This is all background information though. My main problem is, in the Stack Trace it only contains a reference to the line of code where the error occured so I can't trace the error back.

If I put a breakpoint where the error occurs is there a way to go back to the last line of code executed or can you only go forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this functionality at all, but there's an MSDN article that shows how to do what I think you're looking for.

*[The future of debugging is here! Visual Studio 2010 now supports stepping back in the debugger.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/10/21/the-future-of-debugging-is-here-visual-studio-2010-now-supports-stepping-back-in-the-debugger.aspx?Redirected=true)*

Here's the relevant part of his post, although he has some helpful screen shots too:

> IntelliTrace also allows you step back in the debugger! However, the step back functionality isn't enabled by default. You can enable this feature via Tools->Options->IntelliTrace. On the IntelliTrace Options dialog, select the IntelliTrace events and call information option.
>
> After selecting the option, you can now use the debugger step back through the code.

Upon further investigation, it appears that this feature is only in the "ultimate" version of VS. I have the "professional" version of 2010 and 2012 and don't see it in either.

Comment: Thanks Grant. I also have VS 2010 Professional and I don't have that option. I think I may just have to step through the code line by line up to the offending line :'(